# How to making julia code for making spasrs matrix

Tags: matrix, julia

I'm going to make a 48*48 matrix with Julia's code, but I'm going to make a sparse matrix with a value of zero except for a specific matrix. But one value is located in several rows and columns, but there may or may not be a rule. How do I create Julia code so that the index is one value by entering an index of rows and columns?
For example, row 1, row 2, row 4, row 6, row 9, row 11 contain the letter 2r3
How do I create a Julia code that contains the letters r3 in row 2, row 5, row 7, row 6, row 8, and row 10 and row 12 and this address contains 2r3, r3 characters and the rest are all 0?

Thank you for reading this answer.

```
for i in 0:15
    a[3i+1, 3i+2] = 2r3
    a[3i+2, 3i+3] = r3
    for i in 0:2
        a[i+1, i+4] = 3r2
        a[i+13, i+16] = 3r2
        a[i+25, i+28] = 3r2
        a[i+37, i+40] = 3r2
        a[i+4, i+7] = 2r2
        a[i+16, i+19] = 2r2
        a[i+28, i+31] = 2r2
        a[i+40, i+43] = 2r2
        a[i+7, i+10] = r2
        a[i+19, i+22] = r2
        a[i+31, i+34] = r2
        a[i+43, i+46] = r2
        for i in 0:11
            a[i+1, i+13] = 3r1
            a[i+13, i+25] = 2r1
            a[i+25, i+37] = r1
        end
    end
end
```

I did try this code but I think there are codes more simple. But I don't know.

Comment: I can't really see any logic to the rules you have in place, so I can't see how it would be shortened

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code I created is a matrix that may or may not have rules, but what I'm curious about is that certain values appear in multiple rows and columns, and I'm curious to implement addresses in multiple rows and columns as codes.

Comment: I'm curious about the Julia code where rows and columns are indexed so that multiple rows and columns have the same value.

Comment: I agree with @Mark that I cannot see the logic of this implementation - the redefinition of `i` within the same loop is concerning. If you're just looking to access multiple rows and columns at the same time, you can use vectors of indices (e.g., `a[[1, 3], 2]` returns the vector `[a[1, 2]; a[3, 2]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have indexes:

```
is = [1, 7, 9, 22];
js = [3, 15, 18, 21];
```

Than you can create a sparse array holding the same values (here 33) as:

```
julia> a = sparse(is, js, 33)
22×21 SparseMatrixCSC{Int64, Int64} with 4 stored entries:
⎡⠀⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⎤
⎢⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠄⠀⠀⠀⎥
⎢⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠀⠀⎥
⎢⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⎥
⎢⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⎥
⎣⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠂⎦
```

If you want to update several locations at once to a single value you could do:

```
setindex!.(Ref(a), 33, 4:6, [2,4,6])
```

Note that constructing the array with `sparse` is more efficient than performing several updates.